# Function handler in jQuery .off() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can somebody explain, why script behave so:
when i declare function fn inside #wrapper click handler, .off() method doesn't remove the handler from #cover.

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', 'button', function (){
function fn(){
  alert('on')
}
    if($(this).is('#add')){
        $('#info').text('event added')
        $('#cover').on('click', fn)
    }

    if($(this).is('#remove')){
        $('#info').text('event removed');
        $('#cover').off('click', fn);
    }
})
```

But when its outside (global scope) it works fine.

```
function fn(){
  alert('on')
}
$('#wrapper').on('click', 'button', function (){

    if($(this).is('#add')){
        $('#info').text('event added')
        $('#cover').on('click', fn)
    }

    if($(this).is('#remove')){
        $('#info').text('event removed');
        $('#cover').off('click', fn);
    }
})
```

JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b34f3vm2/) here

Answer (score 0):

The former's question is that you will redefine `fn` when you click your button again，in   other words, your `on` and `off` function received parameter `fn` is different completely.

Answer (score 0):

it's a matter of scope. If defined inside $('#wrapper').on('click' the `fn` variable will contain a reference to the function and it will be another reference every time

So, `off` will try to remove the event by removing a reference which is different than the one initially set with `on`

If you define `fn` in the global scope, it will hold the same reference all throughout the execution